# How to properly set section headings in upper case?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

I used to set section headings in uppercase with the `sectsty` package `\MakeUppercase`. But this gives problems when using references in section headings. So how does one do it properly?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item [Keyword\label{key}] This is the description text.
\end{description}

\section{Here it does not work: \nameref{key}}

Here it works: \nameref{key}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an expandable version of `\nameref`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\MakeUppercase}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\enameref[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname r@#1\endcsname\relax
  ??\typeout{^^JLaTeX Warning: Reference #1 undefined on input line \the\inputlineno}%
  \else
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@thirdoffive\csname r@#1\endcsname
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item [Keyword\label{key}] This is the description text.
\end{description}

\section{Here it does not work: \enameref{key}}

Here it works: \nameref{key}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I must somehow have overlooked your reply. Yes, that works. Now I wonder: why is this not the default definition of nameref? Also, how would I overwrite the default nameref command to use the expandable version instead. I tried to just remove the "e" in your newcommand but that didn't work.