# Custom clever ref and and short captions giving error

Tags: captions, cleveref

I have been using the following modification of `\Cref` in my document to provide names to theorems and lemmas if one is given (as I think it reads nicer). As in the MWE ([based on this answer to a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436430/106804)).

However, I just noticed that when I have a custom command in the short caption field I get the following error: `Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 68`. I have commented this line out so it compiles for now, but I have several of these scattered throughout many short captions. Is there a fix?

**MWE**

(`\caption[\oliver's short caption]{\oliver's figure}` causes the issues.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{extarticle}


\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,graphicx,etoolbox,nameref,amsthm,cleveref,xspace}
% Have theorems and lemmas be referenced by name if applicable.
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd{\cref}{\@osmcref{cref}}
\renewrobustcmd{\Cref}{\@osmcref{Cref}}
\def\@osmcref#1#2{%
    \begingroup
    \ifcsundef{r@#2}
    {}
    {\edef\@osmcref@name{%
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
            \@thirdoffive\csname r@#2\endcsname}}%
    \ifcsundef{r@#2@cref}
    {}
    {\cref@gettype{#2}{\@osmcref@type}}%
    \ifboolexpr{not test {\ifdefvoid{\@osmcref@name}}
        and (test {\ifdefstring{\@osmcref@type}{theorem}}
        or test {\ifdefstring{\@osmcref@type}{lemma}})}
    {\nameref{#2} (\@cref{#1}{#2})}
    {\@cref{#1}{#2}}%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
% Give bold names to definitions and similar environments. 
\makeatletter
\def\th@plain{%
    \thm@notefont{}% same as heading font
    \itshape % body font
}
\def\th@definition{%
    \thm@notefont{}% same as heading font
    \normalfont % body font
}
\makeatother
% Giving correct theorem and lemma environments. 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
% Naming these nicely.
\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}
\Crefname{lemma}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
\Crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}


\newcommand{\oliver}{Oliver\xspace}


\begin{document}
    \section{Commands and short captions}
    \label{sec}

    \begin{lemma}\label{noname}
        Extremely important lemma that has no name.
    \end{lemma}

    \begin{lemma}[Fatou's lemma]\label{boringLemma}
        This is some boring statement.
    \end{lemma}

    \begin{theorem}[Fubini's Theorem]\label{awesomeTheorem}
        This is a really awesome statement.
    \end{theorem}

    \Cref{fig} Doesn't work when I have \verb|\oliver| in the short caption. 

    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        Something interesting.
        \caption[Oliver's short caption]{\oliver's figure}
%        \caption[\oliver's short caption]{\oliver's figure} % The troublesome line.
        \label{fig}
    \end{figure}

    We have \Cref{boringLemma} and \Cref{awesomeTheorem}. Whereas \Cref{noname} doesn't have anything interesting.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is "Don't use `\xspace`" an acceptable answer? (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/35864)

Comment: Not really, because sometimes I would like to follow the command with either a space or punctuation, and `\xspace` ensures this is formatted correctly. e.g. `\oliver likes this figure` would remove the space.

Comment: In that case you could write `\oliver{} likes this figure` if you don't use  `\xspace`. I will have a look if I can find out how often exactly I need to expand the definition, but I can't promise anything.

Comment: I have previously used the `\oliver{}` and `\oliver/` variants but found these ugly, and then saw `\xspace` and until now I have been getting along happily with it.

Answer (score 3):

The unprotected `\edef` was a bit too eager. Try

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\expandthrice{%
  \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}
\renewrobustcmd{\cref}{\@osmcref{cref}}
\renewrobustcmd{\Cref}{\@osmcref{Cref}}
\def\@osmcref#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \ifcsundef{r@#2}
      {}
      {\edef\@osmcref@name{\expandthrice{%
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
         \@thirdoffive\csname r@#2\endcsname}}}%
    \ifcsundef{r@#2@cref}
      {}
      {\cref@gettype{#2}{\@osmcref@type}}%
    \ifboolexpr{not test {\ifdefvoid{\@osmcref@name}}
                and (test {\ifdefstring{\@osmcref@type}{thm}}
                     or test {\ifdefstring{\@osmcref@type}{lemma}})}
      {\nameref{#2} (\@cref{#1}{#2})}
      {\@cref{#1}{#2}}%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

or this beauty

```
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd{\cref}{\@osmcref{cref}}
\renewrobustcmd{\Cref}{\@osmcref{Cref}}
\def\@osmcref#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \ifcsundef{r@#2}
      {}
      {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
         \expandafter\expandafter\def
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
         \expandafter\expandafter\@osmcref@name
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
         \expandafter\expandafter{%
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
         \@thirdoffive\csname r@#2\endcsname}}%
    \ifcsundef{r@#2@cref}
      {}
      {\cref@gettype{#2}{\@osmcref@type}}%
    \ifboolexpr{not test {\ifdefvoid{\@osmcref@name}}
                and (test {\ifdefstring{\@osmcref@type}{thm}}
                     or test {\ifdefstring{\@osmcref@type}{lemma}})}
      {\nameref{#2} (\@cref{#1}{#2})}
      {\@cref{#1}{#2}}%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

instead.

I have updated my answer to [Clever Ref to only give theorem names.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436420/35864) with the seven `\expandafter`s monster.

The first solution with `\expandthrice` expands the contents of `\@osmcref@name`  three times by placing it in an `\edef` (which normally tries to expand as far as possible) but stopping the expansion after three steps with `\expandthrice` (essentially this is `etoolbox`'s `\expandonce` but for three expansion steps). The second solution with the seven `\expandafter`s immediately only expands the contents of `\@osmcref@name` three times before saving. I somehow feel that the second solution is a bit nicer because it does not define a new command and because it performs the necessary expansion steps explicitly, whereas the first solution stops an explicit full expansion in the right place.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between these two? and possibly a recommendation about which solution?

Comment: @oliversm There should be no difference (though I would not be too surprised if I am proven wrong on that). My gut instinct prefers the second solution (that's why I updated my other answer with that), but I don't have a good Texnical reason to think it is better.

Comment: +1 for outstanding use of the term "thrice". :-)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7703/35864 might be of interest to understand all the `\expandafter`s